# How to decompose the relation into 5NF?

Tags: database-normalization

The [example](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) provided in the Fifth Normal Form has ACP(Agent, Company, Product) relation with the following data:

```
-----------------------------
| AGENT | COMPANY | PRODUCT |
|-------+---------+---------|
| Smith | Ford    | car     | 
| Smith | Ford    | truck   | 
| Smith | GM      | car     | 
| Smith | GM      | bus     | 
| Jones | Ford    | car     | 
-----------------------------
```

Rule applied is if an agent sells a certain product, and he represents a company making that product, then he sells that product for that company.

The relation is decomposed into 3 relations according to constratint 3D: **AC(agent, company)**, **AP(agent, product)** and **CP(company, product)**. Hence the join dependency is ***{(agent, company), (agent, product),(company, product)}**. According to the definition of 5NF, **a table R is in fifth normal form (5NF) or project-join normal form (PJ/NF) if and only if every join dependency in R is implied by the keys of R**. But none of the projections contain a key, since the key is {agent, company, product} itself.

Another [example](https://books.google.com.np/books?id=EFUn2u6klHkC&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=3D%20constraint%205NF&source=bl&ots=iB2XYwT1lI&sig=ruYzhSi2JH0DRbMyFGg-cF5qG3s&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=3D%20constraint%205NF&f=false) provided in the book by C.J. Date contains a similar relation shipments(suppier_number, part_number, project_number) and the relation is decomposed similarly stating constratint 3D. However, the definition of 5NF doesn't state about the constratint 3D.

So, I have a few questions on the scenario presented above:

1. What is constratint 3D?
2. What if the relation has one more attribute "region" making ACPR(agent, company, product, region)?

Comment: Since the JD  *{(agent, company), (agent, product),(company, product)}  is not implied by the key attribute, can we say the relation ACP is not in 5NF? However, the JD holds in ACP because ACP can be created again from the projections without losing any information.

Comment: *"But none of the projections contain a key..."* Isn't a candidate key for CP the pair of columns {company, product}? Think about it.